# NullPointerException trying to read Parcel String[]

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I am getting a NullPointerException when I am trying to read back a `String[]` when I create an object from [Parcel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeInt(floors);
    out.writeStringArray(indoorMaps);

}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Building> CREATOR
    = new Parcelable.Creator<Building>() {
    public Building createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Building(in);
    }

public Building[] newArray(int size) {
    return new Building[size];
}
};

private Building(Parcel in) {   
    floors = in.readInt();
    in.readStringArray(indoorMaps);
}
```

So indoorMaps is an attribute of my class, and it a `String[]`, but I get the NullPointerException. I have checked the [dev's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#readStringArray%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) but there's nothing there.
I followed [this tutorial](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html) and they are using `readStringArray` in there.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Could you please add the stacktrace with highlighted line in the code  where it throws NullPointerException

Comment: The NullPointerException is thrown in this link: in.readStringArray(indoorMaps);

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are giving `Parcel` a `null` array when calling `readStringArray`. For it to work, you would have to initialize `indoorMaps`. You probably want `createStringArray` instead.

Comment: you are right, by adding indoorMaps = new String[floors]; before readStringArray it fixes the problem. I thought readStringArray did that for me. Thanks!

Comment: @marimaf: `readStringArray` can't allocate the array for you, since it cannot change the object the reference argument points to. `createStringArray` does not take a reference, and does create the array for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Wondering why I didn't find your answer two days ago :P